# Any addition which appeared or have appeared in recent times

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

Yavanika is one of the latest additions to good drama which **appeared/have appeared** in recent times.

If I say**which appeared in recent times**,  will that be considered wrong?  As far as tense of the sentence is considered, I do not think there will be any error by using only **appeared**. But my book says that have appeared is correct.  But I believe **have appeared** is only changing then tense of the sentence not meaning. Suggestions please.

Comment: I agree (that either is fine). However, I prefer *have appeared* in this specific sentence for some inexplicable reason. Perhaps it's easier to internalize the additions which happened several times.

Comment: I would use ***has** appeared* to match the singular subject.

Comment: Careful with that. The meaning of the sentence changes depending on whether the verb is singular or plural. Make it plural, and the reference to additions to good drama appearing in recent years is clear. That is "additions to good drama" is the subject. Make it singular, and "Yavanika" has appeared in recent years, but the scope of the additions to good drama could encompass a larger time period. One would also need to add a comma: "...latest additions to good drama, which has...."